# Why does Firefox 102.15.1esr think it's up-to-date over a month after 115.1.0esr is released?

Tags: firefox

as the saying goes "A picture is worth a thousand words", what's going on here?
[image]

Firefox 115.1.0esr was released 1 August, so why does 102.15.1esr think it's up-to-date on 13 September?

Is there perhaps a bug with 102.15.1esr preventing it from auto updating, and even detecting that a new version has been released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that page only says it was "first offered" not actually released.

If you go to the [Firefox enterprise page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/enterprise/#download) and select the 64-bit ESR release from the 64-bit download then it offers 102.15.1esr as the download.

That is still the latest version.

It is corroborated by https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/organizations/notes/ which also currently redirects to the 102.15.1 release notes. That link comes from Mozilla [Where to find release notes for Firefox for Enterprise](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/where-find-release-notes-firefox-enterprise)

Version 115 is presumably still "early access" and not officially released yet. While 115 is out in the wild it does not seem to have been switched to as the "official" ESR release.

Comment: well that is confusing. Mozilla should have advertised it as "beta" or "early access" or "preview" or something <.<  - anyway thanks!

Comment: @hanshenrik  Yeah, it's kinda odd as Google results also show 115 as being the "latest". I can only find a forum post that says the official release of 115 ESR will be "in september" with 115.3 https://support.mozilla.org/mk/questions/1415736 following the release calendar link suggests september 26 as the proper release date...

Comment: I think it may be a unique situation. Version 102 is the current ESR.  Version 115 is the final release for users of Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 and will be the next official ESR release, AFAIK.